# Can I add an organisation's finance contact to the invoice

Tags: tokens, invoice

We have edited the workflow invoice template and have the name and address of the member organisation as the address block and would like to add the Member Organisation's Finance Contact display name to the address.  Is there a civi token for this?

Or is there an extension that is available that could help with this?

Is this possible?

Many thanks
Sandra

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [Related Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/related-tokens) extension.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Is there a way to install this.  we have the option to add extensions but this extension isn't in there.  Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have shell or ftp access you can upload it. (See [docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/)  ) Alternatively you can ask the extension's maintainer to go through the [Automated Distribution process](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/publish/#automated-distribution) so that it appears in the list of extensions you can enable with the GUI.